# Watchpoints for shared objects

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

How can I add a watchpoint in `.gdbinit` for a specific memory location which is going to be allocated on the heap from within a shared object `.so`?

The following would work if the .so would be already loaded:

```
watch *((TOKEN*)0x084E4C40)
```

However I want to put this in .gdbinit, but that doesn't work, because it has no knowledge about the TOKEN data type, saying:

> No symbol "TOKEN" in current context.

If I do wait until the .so is loaded, I can do that.

For breakpoints I was able to do:

```
set breakpoint pending on
```

However there seems to be nothing similar for watchpoints.

The only thing I could imagine is to somehow load the debugging symbols from the .so file right before setting the watchpoint.

But how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the symbol, only the size of the memory chunk you want to watch. Use this command

`watch *(char(*)[NNN])0x084E4C40`

where `NNN` is `sizeof(TOKEN)`.